# How to use a python language server in Gitpod (VSCode for Web)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, gitpod

Pylance isn't available for non-Microsoft builds of Vscode. I'm trying to have some kind of replacement, but everything I find isn't what Pylance does.

https://www.gitpod.io/docs/references/ides-and-editors/vscode-extensions#use-of-microsoft-owned-extensions-in-gitpod

How could I get something in Gitpod Web that does color coding and intellisense? Linting would also be nice, but there are plenty of those that I could use.

I've found Pyright, which I wanted to work, but it doesn't seem to. It could be that it's broken in the same way that Pylance is in Gitpod. I have installed the vscode extension, but when I go to settings and type `python.languageServer: "", Pyright isn't one available. Is pyright a language server? I've heard that it is.

Is there any other language servers for python available on Gitpod Web? Surely anyone else working in python on Gitpod Web has come across this issue.

Comment: Pylance only applies to VsCode. I don't know much about `gitpod`. Have you tried Jedi?

Comment: When I set the language server to Jedi in ‘settings.json’ and when I set it to None, there is no difference. This leads me to believe that either Jedi isn’t that good (it doesn’t do much color coding or intelligence at all), or Jedi is disabled for the same reason Pylance is - it’s a Microsoft product and only available in official builds of Vscode. I’m not sure about this, though. Really I’d like some way to debug this, but right now I’m stuck at “It doesn’t work, what are my alternatives?”